# Authentication failure on upgrade to 14.04

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 14.04

I was in the middle of upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04 when my internet service went down. The upgrade aborted. On switching to another network and trying `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`, I get the following output and error:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [198 B]
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,148 kB]
Fetched 1,148 kB in 0s (0 B/s)
authenticate 'trusty.tar.gz' against 'trusty.tar.gz.gpg' 
exception from gpg: GnuPG exited non-zero, with code 1
Debug information: 


gpg: Signature made Sat 12 Apr 2014 11:55:14 PM EAT using DSA key ID ********
gpg: /tmp/update-manager-QyUNc1/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: BAD signature from "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>"

Authentication failed
Authenticating the upgrade failed. There may be a problem with the network or with the server.
```

What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: This may be temporary glitch. Try again, and if the problem persists, edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to switch back to the original network. The upgrade resumes on trying the command. Perhaps the key is network/IP specific.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Stormvirux it answers the second part of the question, in case anyone has a similar problem. I haven't selected it as the answer because the first part hasn't been answered.